# PHP array elements replace

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I want to make some encryption and write numbers
I used:

```
$a = [100,101,102,103,104,105]
function decrition (array $a){
return preg_replace('/101/','a',$a);
}
```

And it's returns me all letters "a" for each 101 in array. 
How can I change next? 101 to "b", 102 to "c" etc.

```
 return preg_replace('[101|102|103|104|105]','a',$a);
```

this method replace all this numbers to letter "a"

```
return preg_replace('[101|102|103|104|105','a|b|c|d|e',$a);
```

unfortunately it's not working

Comment: `I want to make some encryption` Please don't try and [reinvent the wheel](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to treat it as a string?

```
<?php

$a = [ 101, 102, 103 ];

$replace_array = array(101 => "a", 102 => "b");
$b = array_map(function($val) use ($replace_array) {
  return (isset($replace_array[$val]) ? $replace_array[$val] : $val);
}, $a);

var_dump($a, $b);
```

Gives the following output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(101)
  [1]=>
  int(102)
  [2]=>
  int(103)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  int(103)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
$test = str_replace($a, array('a','b','c','d','e','f'), $a);
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works

```
 return str_replace(['101', '102', '103', '104', '105'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], $a);
```